# TeXstudio no longer compiles properly/at all nor downloads packages after fresh install on new HDD

Tags: packages, miktex, texstudio, compilation-error

To keep it short: I installed a new HDD into my computer, installed Win10 on that HDD and brought all my data over from my old drive onto the new one. I did a clean reinstall of TeXstudio and MiKTeX just to be sure.

Ever since then, my .tex files no longer compile properly, giving errors most of the time and requiring me to fiddle around all the time.

It also stopped downloading packages on its own. Currently I'm getting the error "Unfortunately, the package fancyhdr (but can be any package) could not be installed. Please check the log file: C:\Users\crota\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\pdflatex.log Process exited with error(s)"

The log file gives me this wall of text

```
2022-05-02 10:17:55,061+0200 INFO  pdflatex - this process (5960) started by 'texstudio' with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode testing.tex
2022-05-02 10:17:55,069+0200 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
2022-05-02 10:17:55,069+0200 INFO  pdflatex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2022-05-02 10:17:55,095+0200 INFO  pdflatex - going to create file: pdflatex.fmt
2022-05-02 10:17:55,139+0200 INFO  pdflatex.core - start process: initexmf --dump-by-name=pdflatex --engine=pdftex
2022-05-02 10:18:06,630+0200 INFO  pdflatex - installing package moderncv triggered by tex/latex/moderncv\moderncv.cls
2022-05-02 10:18:06,647+0200 INFO  pdflatex.packagemanager - going to download https://api2.miktex.org/hello
2022-05-02 10:18:06,831+0200 INFO  pdflatex.packagemanager - going to download https://api2.miktex.org/repositories?&releaseState=Stable&orderBy=ranking&take=1
2022-05-02 10:18:06,849+0200 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: starting package maintenance...
2022-05-02 10:18:06,849+0200 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: installation directory: C:\Users\crota\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2022-05-02 10:18:06,849+0200 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: package repository: https://ctan.space-pro.be/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
2022-05-02 10:18:07,108+0200 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: package repository digest: 9693e41391afbcca7c929e975587eade
2022-05-02 10:18:07,108+0200 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: going to download 34077 bytes
2022-05-02 10:18:07,108+0200 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: going to install 39 file(s) (1 package(s))
2022-05-02 10:18:07,912+0200 INFO  pdflatex.packagemanager - installing package moderncv
2022-05-02 10:18:07,913+0200 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: downloading https://ctan.space-pro.be/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/moderncv.tar.lzma...
2022-05-02 10:18:07,914+0200 INFO  pdflatex.packagemanager - going to download https://ctan.space-pro.be/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/moderncv.tar.lzma
2022-05-02 10:18:08,125+0200 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: 0.03 MB, 1.29 Mbit/s
2022-05-02 10:18:08,129+0200 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: extracting files from moderncv.tar.lzma...
2022-05-02 10:18:08,714+0200 INFO  pdflatex.core - start process: initexmf --mkmaps
2022-05-02 10:18:09,256+0200 FATAL pdflatex - The executed process did not succeed.
2022-05-02 10:18:09,256+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\mkfntmap.EXE", exitCode="1"
2022-05-02 10:18:09,256+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Source: 
2022-05-02 10:18:09,256+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 0
2022-05-02 10:18:09,489+0200 INFO  pdflatex - this process (5960) finishes with exit code 1
2022-05-02 10:18:09,525+0200 WARN  miktex.core - still open: testing.tex
2022-05-02 10:18:09,525+0200 WARN  miktex.core - still open: C:\Users\crota\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/moderncv\moderncv.cls
2022-05-02 10:18:09,525+0200 WARN  miktex.core - still open: C:\Users\crota\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty
2022-05-02 10:18:22,144+0200 INFO  pdflatex - this process (23264) started by 'texstudio' with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode testing.tex
2022-05-02 10:18:22,151+0200 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
2022-05-02 10:18:22,151+0200 INFO  pdflatex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2022-05-02 10:18:28,074+0200 INFO  pdflatex - installing package colortbl triggered by tex/latex/colortbl\colortbl.sty
2022-05-02 10:18:28,079+0200 INFO  pdflatex.packagemanager - going to download https://api2.miktex.org/repositories?&releaseState=Stable&orderBy=ranking&take=1
2022-05-02 10:18:28,255+0200 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: starting package maintenance...
2022-05-02 10:18:28,256+0200 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: installation directory: C:\Users\crota\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2022-05-02 10:18:28,256+0200 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: package repository: https://ftp.rrze.uni-erlangen.de/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
2022-05-02 10:18:28,510+0200 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: package repository digest: 9693e41391afbcca7c929e975587eade
2022-05-02 10:18:28,511+0200 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: going to download 607791 bytes
2022-05-02 10:18:28,511+0200 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: going to install 6 file(s) (1 package(s))
2022-05-02 10:18:29,300+0200 INFO  pdflatex.packagemanager - installing package colortbl
2022-05-02 10:18:29,301+0200 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: downloading https://ftp.rrze.uni-erlangen.de/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/colortbl.tar.lzma...
2022-05-02 10:18:29,302+0200 INFO  pdflatex.packagemanager - going to download https://ftp.rrze.uni-erlangen.de/ctan/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/colortbl.tar.lzma
2022-05-02 10:18:29,655+0200 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: 0.61 MB, 13.81 Mbit/s
2022-05-02 10:18:29,660+0200 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: extracting files from colortbl.tar.lzma...
2022-05-02 10:18:30,200+0200 INFO  pdflatex.core - start process: initexmf --mkmaps
2022-05-02 10:18:30,619+0200 FATAL pdflatex - The executed process did not succeed.
2022-05-02 10:18:30,619+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\mkfntmap.EXE", exitCode="1"
2022-05-02 10:18:30,619+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Source: 
2022-05-02 10:18:30,619+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 0
2022-05-02 10:18:30,910+0200 INFO  pdflatex - this process (23264) finishes with exit code 1
2022-05-02 10:18:30,944+0200 WARN  miktex.core - still open: testing.tex
2022-05-02 10:18:30,944+0200 WARN  miktex.core - still open: C:\Users\crota\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/moderncv\moderncv.cls
2022-05-02 10:23:16,488+0200 INFO  pdflatex - this process (11536) started by 'texstudio' with command line: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode testing.tex
2022-05-02 10:23:16,495+0200 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
2022-05-02 10:23:16,495+0200 INFO  pdflatex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2022-05-02 10:23:16,518+0200 INFO  pdflatex - going to create file: pdflatex.fmt
2022-05-02 10:23:16,564+0200 INFO  pdflatex.core - start process: initexmf --dump-by-name=pdflatex --engine=pdftex
2022-05-02 10:23:26,152+0200 INFO  pdflatex - installing package fancyhdr triggered by tex/latex/fancyhdr\fancyhdr.sty
2022-05-02 10:23:26,157+0200 INFO  pdflatex.packagemanager - going to download https://api2.miktex.org/hello
2022-05-02 10:23:26,336+0200 INFO  pdflatex.packagemanager - going to download https://api2.miktex.org/repositories?&releaseState=Stable&orderBy=ranking&take=1
2022-05-02 10:23:26,354+0200 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: starting package maintenance...
2022-05-02 10:23:26,354+0200 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: installation directory: C:\Users\crota\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2022-05-02 10:23:26,354+0200 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: package repository: https://ctan.kako-dev.de/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
2022-05-02 10:23:26,645+0200 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: package repository digest: 9693e41391afbcca7c929e975587eade
2022-05-02 10:23:26,645+0200 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: going to download 838456 bytes
2022-05-02 10:23:26,645+0200 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: going to install 7 file(s) (1 package(s))
2022-05-02 10:23:27,444+0200 INFO  pdflatex.packagemanager - installing package fancyhdr
2022-05-02 10:23:27,445+0200 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: downloading https://ctan.kako-dev.de/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/fancyhdr.tar.lzma...
2022-05-02 10:23:27,446+0200 INFO  pdflatex.packagemanager - going to download https://ctan.kako-dev.de/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/fancyhdr.tar.lzma
2022-05-02 10:23:29,775+0200 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: 0.84 MB, 2.88 Mbit/s
2022-05-02 10:23:29,781+0200 INFO  pdflatex - mpm: extracting files from fancyhdr.tar.lzma...
2022-05-02 10:23:30,372+0200 INFO  pdflatex.core - start process: initexmf --mkmaps
2022-05-02 10:23:31,006+0200 FATAL pdflatex - The executed process did not succeed.
2022-05-02 10:23:31,006+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Info: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\mkfntmap.EXE", exitCode="1"
2022-05-02 10:23:31,006+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Source: 
2022-05-02 10:23:31,006+0200 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 0
2022-05-02 10:23:31,255+0200 INFO  pdflatex - this process (11536) finishes with exit code 1
2022-05-02 10:23:31,290+0200 WARN  miktex.core - still open: testing.tex
2022-05-02 10:23:31,290+0200 WARN  miktex.core - still open: C:\Users\crota\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/moderncv\moderncv.cls
```

I tried searching the web and different package manuals and the TeXstudio user manual for the past few days, but I just couldn't find a solution to my specific problem.

EDIT: As per @UlrikeFischer s advice, I downloaded all the packaged MiKTeX offers and added one of the several errors I get in the following example code.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,titlepage]{moderncv}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fontawesome}  %Paket für schönere Symbole bei den persönlichen Daten.
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[left=1.0cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.7cm, bottom=1.7cm]{geometry}
\author{My Name}


\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}
\moderncvicons{awesome}

%Die persönlichen Daten:
\name{My}{Name}
\title{Lebenslauf}
\address{Address}{PLZ}
\phone[mobile]{Number}
\phone[phone]{Number2}
\email{email@mailmail.mail}
%\extrainfo{Hier können extra Informaitonen stehen.}
\quote{{\footnotesize ''When a crisis
        shapes up, you don't waste energy wishing for information
        or skills you haven't got. You dig in and handle it
        as best you can with what you've got.''  Aahz}}


\begin{document}
    \makecvtitle
    
    \section{Persönliche Daten}
    \cvline{Geburtstag:}{Birthday}
    \cvline{Geburtsort:}{City}
    
\end{document}
```

The errors this gives me look like this and I only found out it relates to the symbols that are trying to be used for the \mobile and \phone command:

```
LaTeX3 Error: Control sequence \faAdjust already defined. ...:nnnnn{\faAdjust}{adjust}{free0}{3}{"F042}
```

Comment: if you have enough disk space I suggest that you go to the miktex console and install as a first step all missing packages. That will avoid that miktex has to download all your missing packages during the compilation.  If you then still get errors: make a small complete example showing one of them.

Comment: Thank you, @UlrikeFischer, I edited my post with an example portion taken straight from one of the documents that 100% used to work before I changed over to my new hard drive.

Comment: don't load fontawesome, that clashes with fontawesome5 loaded by moderncv.

Comment: Wow, I am amazed that it was this simple to fix. I am still very baffled how it managed to compile just fine a week ago, but I'll accept the solution. Thanks!
As for the question on why BibLaTeX no longer seems to be loaded but instead only Biber or BibTeX, should I post a separate question about it?

Comment: The code example does not appear to include any citations, so running BibTeX or Biber does not make a lot of sense. Presumably you have bibliography/citation issues with a document that actually cites something. Note that even on your old installation you shouldn't have gotten a message reading `This is BibLaTeX blabla`. `biblatex` is a LaTeX package and not an executable. The "This is ..." messages should come from BibTeX or Biber. If you get a different executable than before, maybe your editor is not configured correctly.

Comment: you updated your texsystem and probably got a newer moderncv. I think they changed the handling of the `\moderncvicons{awesome}` a bit (but I don't use the class so I don't know).

Comment: That said, a new question about the `biblatex` issue with an example that reproduces that specific issue is probably best. Then this question here can be answered with the font awesome comment and the other question can be addressed independently.

Comment: Alright, thanks to all here! I'll post the question about biblatex in a minute then.

Comment: I removed the allusion to the `biblatex` issue in this question, since there is a proper question about that at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/642766/35864 now.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the package `fontawesome` clashed with the package `fontawesome5` that `moderncv` loads up.
Not using that package, fixed the error.

Answer (score 1):

As bad as it sounds, I think it's always best to download full miktex and then install the whole thing rather than installing one by one on demand. Sometimes updated packages may even have compatibility issue depending on the version you are installing. Maybe try that if you have the bandwidth to go for it.