# biblatex no longer compiles entries with german umlauts in their ID

Tags: biblatex, texstudio, biber

I installed a new hard drive, moved my Win10 installation and all data over to it. Got a clean reinstall of TeXstudio and MiKTeX. I made my bibliography using `biblatex`  and ever since the change to the new HDD, it no longer compiles citations that have umlauts in their bibliography ID.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{quellenBA.bib}
\author{None other than Me}
\title{Something to test}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    
    According to \cite{Antifungal-LAB-Propioni-Biopreservation}, this is true. But \cite{Probiotika-präbiotika-def-einsatz,Hausschlacht-NubaRohPök} disagree.
    
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

It produces this log upon compilation:

```
Process started: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\biber.exe"  "testing"

INFO - This is Biber 2.17
INFO - Logfile is 'testing.blg'
INFO - Reading 'testing.bcf'
INFO - Found 3 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex file 'quellenBA.bib' for section 0
INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'quellenBA.bib'
INFO - Overriding locale 'de-DE' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
INFO - Overriding locale 'de-DE' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
INFO - Sorting list 'nty/global//global/global' of type 'entry' with template 'nty' and locale 'de-DE'
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'de-DE'
INFO - Writing 'testing.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
INFO - Output to testing.bbl
WARN - I didn't find a database entry for 'Probiotika-pr^^c3^^a4biotika-def-einsatz' (section 0)
WARN - I didn't find a database entry for 'Hausschlacht-NubaRohP^^c3^^b6k' (section 0)
INFO - WARNINGS: 2
Process exited normally



Process started: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe"  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "testing".tex

Process exited normally


Process started: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe"  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "testing".tex

Process exited normally
```

And it gives me this output:

[image]

I understand that the two warnings mean that it thinks there are no database entries. But there are, it just tries finding the entry with their umlauts written that way.
The corresponding `.bib` entries are:

```
@incollection{Antifungal-LAB-Propioni-Biopreservation,
    title = {Antifungal lactic acid bacteria and propionibacteria for food biopreservation},
    editor = {Lacroix, C.},
    booktitle = {Protective Cultures, Antimicrobial Metabolites and Bacteriophages for Food and Beverage Biopreservation},
    publisher = {Woodhead Publishing},
    pages = {27-62},
    year = {2011},
    series = {Woodhead Publishing Series in Food Science, Technology and Nutrition},
    doi = {10.1533/9780857090522.1.27},
    url = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9781845696696500029},
    author = {S. Miescher Schwenninger and L. Meile and C. Lacroix},
}

@article{Probiotika-präbiotika-def-einsatz,
    author = {Schulz, S. and Kunz, C.},
    title = {Probiotika, Präbiotika, Colonic food Definitionen und mögliche Einsatzgebiete},
    journal = {Monatsschrift Kinderheilkunde},
    doi = {10.1007/s00112-002-0507-y},
    year = {2002},
    pages = {808 - 816},
}

@online{Hausschlacht-NubaRohPök,
    author = {o.N.},
    title = {Reifekulturen zur Herstellung von Rohschinken},
    url = {https://hausschlachtebedarf.de/gewuerze/zusatzstoffe/2133/30-g-reifekulturen-zur-herstellung-von-rohschinken?c=3},
    note = {zuletzt geöffnet: 21.03.2022},
    organization = {Nubassa},
}
```

It used to work without any issue and I changed nothing on the file itself after migrating to a new HDD.

I tried searching for answers online, but all my BibLaTeX questions seem to point me to questions related to Biber that don't seem to give a solution to my problem.

Comment: You have umlauts in your bib key, which requires that you use an Engine with native UTF8-support, e.g. `LuaLaTeX`. Are you using `pdfLaTeX` by any chance? **ETA**: Yes, you are: `Process started: "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe`. Try switching.

Comment: which encoding does your bib file use?

Comment: @Ingmar no, that isn't correct. It works fine for me in a current miktex with pdflatex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I take your word for it, even though I dimly remember having had that issue myself in the past. Might have been some other encoding issue …

Comment: @Ingmar in the past it would have been a problem, but umlauts no longer expand when written to a file (if utf8 is used). That's why they are now safe e.g. in \label and also (mostly) in \cite

Comment: @UlrikeFischer how do I find out the encoding my bib file uses?

Comment: open the bib in texstudio and look what it says about the encoding.

Comment: I think it is encoded in UTF-8? The lower-right settings are de_DE and UTF-8.

Comment: put the tex file, the log-file and the bib in a zip and put them somewhere for download so that one can check the encodings.

Comment: The example document compiles fine for me with the example entries if I make sure that all files are UTF-8-encoded as the `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` suggests. Double-check that all involved files are really UTF-8 encoded. (Since you speak German https://texwelt.de/fragen/2656/wie-uberprufe-ich-die-standardeingabekodierung-in-meinem-editor might help).

Comment: While the example should work as-is, I like to be pretty conservative in the characters I use for internal labels. For a language with Latin-based alphabet such as German I would simply avoid non-ASCII chars by replacing `ö` with `oe` etc. (For languages with non-Latin scripts, or with many accented letters this might not be a feasible option. But for German you can definitely get away with ASCII-only at little cost in terms of convenience.)

Comment: Thank you for the help so far. 
@UlrikeFischer and anyone who's willing to dive in: I've uploaded it the bib, tex file and the pdflatex.log to Dropbox. Hope this link works [Helpplz](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9lnownltlw0qqyz/Bibcompilationproblem.zip?dl=0)

Comment: @moewe According to what I found and the link you provided, everything should be in UTF-8. I also started with ASCII-characters-only until I noticed that umlauts do indeed work and so I happily stopped avoiding them. Guess I'll go back to the tradition of ASCII only from now :(

Comment: show the testing.log (after one pdflatex compilation), it should be in the same folder as your testing file. Did you try with exactly these files?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I put the testing.log [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7fajyi5o1xjl01v/testing.log?dl=0)...at least I think that's the log you meant. It's the only pure text file I can find that is produced upon hitting "Compile" once. 
Unfortunately, I'm unsure what you mean by "Did you try with exactly these files?"

Comment: hm. the only obvious difference I see is that you have older binaries. You have Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.7), while I have 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.3).

Comment: Can you unpack the `.zip` you have uploaded to a new, empty folder on your computer and compile the file as usual, please? Do you still get the error in that case? For me everything works perfectly fine even with your files and they appear to be correctly UTF-8-encoded. Like Ulrike the only real difference in the `.log` files I can see is that my engine is slightly newer than yours. It is worth a shot to update MikTeX. Update MikTeX in both admin and user mode via the Console. Then try again (after deleting the `.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf` files).

Comment: Thank you two! My problem has not been solved, but I very much appreciate your efforts. I tried updating MiKTeX in user and in admin mode via the console and both tell me that there are no updates available and I should check back in tomorrow. Strange. I also unpacked the .zip to an empty folder, compiled it as usual and the error still happens. I guess for now, I'll have to resign myself to avoiding non-ASCII characters in bib entry IDs. I'm just very glad that this happened after I already turned in my thesis lol

Comment: if there are no updates something is wrong with your system. You clearly use an rather old binary. In your log article.cls is from C:\Users\crota\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls, that means you installed in single user mode and there should be no admin mode in the console. Check if you have two tex systems.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I reinstalled MiKTeX in the "install for all users" mode and then tried updating in admin as well as user mode. I thought running it in admin mode, meant right click -> run as administrator, like with most other programs. I also deleted any trace I could find of my former MiKTeX installation on the old hard drive (which is still in use). Still no luck in getting an update. What confuses me the most, is that the setup is straight from the MiKTeX download page. It's even called "basic-miktex-22.3-x64", yet my version after install and initial update is only 20.something.

Comment: I finally solved it. Somehow I had two MiKTeX installations on the same drive and TeXstudio accessed the older one, I presume. When I set the path for each of the commands (the one you find in Configure TeXstudio -> Commands) to the proper target, it finally worked as it should. Thank you all for persevering through this hellhole with me!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the solution was that I had two MiKTeX installations on my drive (no real idea where or when the "wrong one" came to be). I changed the path for each command in Configure TeXstudio -> Commands to the correct target (meaning, I just changed to MiKTeX folder, really, since everything else was the same). Now it works flawlessly.